# A rich and family which is living in comfort and luxury

Tags: word-usage, word-request, idioms, expressions, phrases

I Wonder what do you call **a family** which is most of the time rich and all its members are living a good life and have whatever they need? The idiom/expression/set phrase or even the adjective in my question not only should encapsulate the concept of being wealthy, but also should indicate that the person is living in comfort and luxury and has all the needed facilities at hand. I wonder what would you use to fill in the black below:

> — He has grown up in a ................. family?

I used to think that a "prosperous family" is my needed concept, but reading the meaning of this word I decided to ask a new question about it, while it doesn't convey anything about "comfort".

Comment: Though it doesn't fit the structure of your example sentence, a common phrase to express the same idea would be: "He was born with a silver spoon in his mouth."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people will probably think they mean *exactly* the same thing, but personally I think adjectival ***well-to-do*** best carries the *specific* allusion to OP's request for a terms that includes "comfort and luxury, with all needed facilities at hand". To my mind, the similar term ***well-off*** is much more tightly focused on actual ***wealth***.

It's worth citing [this definition from Collins...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-to-do)

> **well-to-do**
>    *- **showing signs** of being successful; rich*

(They also include ***comfortable*** in their list of synonyms, which I think is relevant.)

Comment: In the UK at least, we also use several expressions for wealth: "comfortably-off" (financially comfortable), "better-off" (than someone specific, or than people in general) and "well-off".

Comment: @jonathanjo: I don't know why that Collins entry identifies it as "American English" - it's more reminiscent of Victorian England to me (but bearing its years well; I don't find it particularly "dated", just a tad "hifalutin"). I just checked the full OED, which only refers to a trivial US/UK distinction in pronunciation (their ***do*** being uncharacteristically more "diphthongy" than ours - somewhat at odds with their preference for ***doo*** over ***dew***).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very much FF. Actually I knew the term, just sometimes, I think providing some hints might deviate the posters' minds. However, you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @A-friend: I'm not sure what you mean about "providing some hints". Do you mean spell out the progressive shift from ***They live well*** (have all the comforts of life) to ***They're rich*** (have lots of money), with ***They're well-to-do / well-off*** sitting somewhere *between* those two identifiably different meanings?

Comment: @A-friend: Oh - in case you didn't know it, you might be interested in ***He does all right***. Colloquial expression meaning ***He's [relatively] well-paid*** (or maybe has a high income from some "non-employment" arrangement, but it always implies *ongoing income*, not just that he was once left a lot of money from a rich relative).

Answer (score 1):

The common phrase is "a rich family". You might also say "a wealthy family" or "a prosperous family". They mean the same thing.